# Can I move to Germany for 1 year to test how it is, with a remote job?

Tags: germany, immigration, family, skilled-migration

I have a remote job since 1 year, and I'm earning 5000 USD a month. In my future plans, I would like to go to Germany to see what it is like to live there.

Is there a chance to go for one year or more while keeping my remote job?

I am not an EU citizen and I don't have a job offer there, and I don't have an university degree (or I do, but 3 years, half term degree for a 5 years career in Information Systems (IT)). I'm already taking German language classes.

I have two children and the reason for the 1 year is so that they can be there the entire school year. They are currently attending a German school in Buenos Aires, Argentina.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue would be that one needs to have a reason to apply for residence permit in Germany.

If one wants be working in Germany as employee (does not matter remote or not), the company should follow German laws, [i.e. pay social and medical insurance, and some kind of registration](https://www.tk.de/firmenkunden/service/fachthemen/ausland/mitarbeiter-anmelden-ohne-deutschen-firmensitz-2088296). If one's company can do it, then one can try to get a residence permit for the purpose of working.

Alternatively, one can become a contractor/freelancer. In that case, one can apply for residence permit for freelancers, §21 (5) AufenthG.

Finally, one can be employed through some payroll company, which is located in Germany.

However, I'm not a lawyer, and I do not have too much experience with getting residence permits for freelancers or foreign companies hiring employees in Germany. I would suggest you to ask a lawyer specialised on immigration law (many of them now work remotely and also speak English) and/or the corresponding consulate for details.

Answer (score 1):

I have made initial and renewal applications for an "Aufenthaltserlaubnis" (residence permit) while working as a postdoc. I believe the permitting process is essentially the same as far as the "Ausländeramt" (Foreigners' Office) is concerned.

The public employee reviewing your materials is ultimately going to have a fair amount of discretion, but

1. You must have German health insurance (Krankenversicherung) - your US or travel insurance is not acceptable
2. You have to have an address (there is a formal requirement to register your address every time you move  - "Meldepflicht")
3. You need to demonstrate that you can finance yourself: this is somewhat subjective and may be a combination of a current work contract with stated wages, current bank statements, some other kind of grant or funding, etc.

I actually have a spare, blank form for the next renewal, so I scanned it so that you can see exactly what is asked of you (and they'll want evidence for all of it!): [German Residence Application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3astmabefxuslic/GermanResidenceApp.pdf?dl=0)
N.B. Mine is from Aachen, where I live but I think the process is nationally more or less consistent.